# Virt-manager and several consoles via sendkey

Tags: ubuntu, installation, ubuntu-18.04, qemu, libvirt

I use this virt-install statement to launch an Ubuntu VM installation, once remote and once locally:

```
virt-install .. \
        --graphics vnc \
        --console pty,target_type=serial \
        --extra-args=\"console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial ..
```

While I can use the Sendkey menu to switch between system consoles locally, remote Qemu connection via SSH does not allow that.

Why?

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to the guest using virt-manager/virt-viewer you are using the Linux virtual consoles which are multiplex allowed switching between consoles. When you connect using SSH you are using a totally different console framework, using a psuedo-PTY. If you want multiple consoles, then just run multiple SSH connections.

Answer (score 0):

The following workaround has helped me.

- install VNC viewer, I used the one from RealVNC
- send ctrl+alt keys via F8 context menu as described in more detail in this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34283/vnc-send-ctrlaltf1-f6-to-server).

So I do not use a local virt-manager to connect to remote virt-install but this workaround with VNC viewer helps me to do my work now.